# Row delimiter SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have the below output in the flat file that comes from database

[image]

I need to get the results below: every time when the file has the letter B after the name it just break the line as you can see below:

[image]

Is that any chance to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Leo

Comment: You can do this in `Notepad++` also very easily if you are not looking for `SSIS` specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what your asking: you want the row to break everytime on 4th column, or only if it's value is "B"? I'm assuming that every time, but it'll be easy to add the condition afterwards.

Split the pipeline with Multicast, and then use Union All to get first 3 columns from first pipeline and other 4 columns from second pipeline:
[image: union All]

Result would look like this:
[image: flow]

If you need to split the row only if 3rd column is "B", then add Conditional Split before Multicast and redirect rows without "B" directly to Union All. The rest of the rows go to Multicast as before. You'll of course need to add more Output Columns in Union All this time, as the result should have same number of columns as source file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all

This is sorted

I prepared different query to extract the data by LETTER, A and B then I used merge files and order by to organize the records.

;)